# List child terms if parent but show nothing on children

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a taxonomy called region with a hierarchical structure;

• Southern Africa
    • Botswana
    • South Africa
    • Zambia
    • Zimbabwe

In my *taxonomy-region.php* template file I would like to list the child terms when on Southern Africa (parent) and show nothing when on Botswana (child).

I have the following code where I'd like it to display:

```
<?php 
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )); ?>
<h5>Countries</h5>
<?php $cats = wp_list_categories( array(
    'parent' => $current_term->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'depth' => 2,
    'title_li' => ''
    )); 
?>
<ul>
  <?php foreach ((array)$cats as $cat) {
    echo '<li><a href="'. get_category_link($cat).'" title="'. $cat->$cat_name .'">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a></li>'; }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reliability, you can get the current term being viewed from the queried object from `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']`

```
$current_term = sanitize_term( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
```

To answer your question, if `Southern Africa` is top level, it should have a parent term ID of `0`. All child terms should have a numeric value as parent which corresponds to the parent term id they belong to.

With this in mind, you can simply check the value of `$current_term->parent`, and if the value is not `0`, hide your code

```
$current_term = sanitize_term( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
if ( 0 == $current_term->parent ) {
    // This is a top level page, show our code

        // ADD YOUR CODE HERE

}
```

Just another tip, I would use `get_terms()` for my list

Comment: Sorry, please recheck, had a slight error in my code

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen, it works perfectly. Just one question; do you mean you would use `get_terms()` in place of `wp_list_categories()`? Would I need to alter the array in that case?

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Personally yes, I would tend to use `get_terms()`, it is a bit faster, but anyways, it really isn't a trainsmash, we are talking ms here. You would need to change one or two parameters though if you want to go the `get_terms()` route. You should go and check out the codex on `get_terms` and play around with it. .